# How can I create unique non-repeating pair combinations from a list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am new to computer programming.

I want to create successive 2-person teams from an even numbered list of players (32 max) but with no repeats until all possible teams have been formed.

For example for 6 players (a thru f) I can generate with itertools.combinations 15 distinct teams. Then I can manually, on paper, in a matrix create 5 sets of 3 unique teams(i.e. [['a','b'],['c','d'], ['e','f']], and similarly ac,bf,de; ae,bc,df; af,bd,ce and ad,be,cf). But I've been unable to write a program (many varied attempts) in python 3.5 to do this. After 5 or fewer iterations I get repeats and some possible teams are not created at all.

I did a search but cannot quite discern which solution applies in my specific case.

Comment: Let's check the "X-Y" problem status: what is the end purpose of this?  Are you trying to set up a full round-robin pairing for 2N players?  That's a slightly different problem, but with known solutions.  If you need to work through the algorithm in a less orderly fashion, as your description implies, then we have a slightly more difficult problem.

Comment: Please share your attempts, even if they don't work. That is exactly what Stack Overflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is *some* complete round-robin pairing, then look up solutions with "round-robin tournament schedule".  You can likely just use the long-known solution illustrated well on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament).

List the players in two rows, half of them in each row, like so:

```
A  B  C
D  E  F
```

You first pairings are AD, BE, CF.  Next, nail **A** in place, and consider the others as a ring:

```
A   B  C
   D    F
     E
```

Rotate the ring clockwise one position ...

```
A   D  B
   E    C
     F
```

... flatten the lower three into one row again:

```
A  D  B
E  F  C
```

Your second round pairings are AE, DF, BC.
Continue this for a total of five rotations; the last one recovers the original pairings.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I would like to submit my code along with a typical scenario of what I am trying to accomplish. Can I just copy code from my text editor (Wingware 101) and paste it so that it appears in a shaded box as with your answer?  I don't understand the advice about backticks, Ctrl-K, etc.

Comment: You should be able to edit that way.  When you're in the edit window, hover over the icons at the top; small help boxes tell you what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a typical scenario of what I'm trying to accomplish:
Roster of about 26 players
Week 1: 18 of 26 show up. I form 9 teams
Week 2: 22 of 26 show up. I form 11 teams but no repeats from Week 1
Week 3: 10 of 26 show up. I form 5 teams but no repeats from Week 1 or Week 2, etc.

The following works, albeit without the past__teams filter applied (yet), with up to 12 players (takes 25 secs) but beyond 12 is unbearably long, and I expect about 24 players.
The program selects the first valid set of teams then ends.  With the additional past__teams filter applied - the whole point of the program - it will have to run even longer.
Is there an alternate approach to this problem or a way to speed it up considerably?

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
import pickle, random
'''the'past__teams.py' file was previously created as follows:
output = open('past__teams.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(past__teams, output)
output.close()'''
players = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
random.shuffle(players)
#load the past__teams file into the program
pkl_file = open('past__teams.pkl', 'rb')
past__teams = pickle.load(pkl_file)
pkl_file.close()

all_pair_combinations= []
tonights_teams = []
for c in combinations(players, 2):
    c = list(c)
    all_pair_combinations.append(c)

def dupe_test(L):
    if len(L) != len(set(L)):
        return True
    return False
y = 0
for t in combinations(all_pair_combinations, int(len(players)/2)):
    t = list(t)
    tt =list(chain(*t))
    y = y +1
    if dupe_test(tt) == False:
        tonights_teams =t
        break
print ()
print ("Tonights_teams: ",y,tonights_teams)
```